# Is Naproxen (medication) approved for flight?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

Is Naproxen an approved FAA medication? I have found 2 separate websites which comment on this type of medication that seem to be somewhat ambiguous, at least to the degree that I'm looking for.

- https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/pharm/dni_dnf/
- https://www.leftseat.com/medcat1.htm

Is there a singular location to find out if a medication is approved or not approved? Specifically I'm looking for Naproxen.

Comment: It is approved on a case-by-case basis, so you would have to go through your medical examiner to get this submitted for approval.

Comment: Naproxen does not fall under any of the categories listed on the FAA page as grounding the person taking it. On your other (non-official list) it's said to be ok unless you're precluded from flying by side effects or by the condition for which you're taking it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no fully authoritative source for this information, other than consulting an AME directly. [AOPA's medication database](https://www.aopa.org/go-fly/medical-resources/medications-database) is considered pretty reliable (and it says Naproxen is allowed) but their generic disclaimer explains why you can't just look up a medication in a list:

> Although these medications are generally allowed by the FAA for flight
>   duties, there are variables with each individual's situation that
>   could render a particular medication inappropriate for flying because
>   of case history or adverse side effects. Some medications are being
>   used "off label". This means that a drug is prescribed for symptoms
>   that do not fall within the FDA's approval guidelines for that drug.
>   This is just one example of why the FAA might not approve a drug that
>   is on the list.

In other words, as with all medical questions you have to consult a  professional to get the right answer for your personal situation.

Comment: For the sake of curiosity, what if one were to strictly go off the medical database  for approved medication and not consult an AME? There are all kinds of medication and I would think it could make it prohibitive at times to contact an AME for every type of medication that one might need to take (tylenol, ibuprofen, etc.) every time they might need to take it.

Comment: First off (until all the third class medical reform is in place) you still need to get a Medical exam to fly and you need to report all recurring medications. As for one off medications and over the counter things you, as PIC need to decide how it effects you and if it will negatively impact your flight. If you are concerned in any way, contact an AME.

Comment: @RyanGriffith I don't think anyone cares about 'typical' OTC stuff if you're just taking it for a day or two and you know there are no side effects. You're expected to [evaluate your own fitness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMSAFE) before every flight anyway. But if you start taking any medication regularly, or you get a new prescription for something, then checking with your AME would be a good idea.

Comment: The reason it is approved case-by-case is because the AME may need to verify the condition, not the medication. For example if you take it for chronic knee pain, the AME may want to verify that you have full range of motion and adequate strength in your knees from a sitting position.